# Symfony 5 CollectionType show "dummy" if no datas for the CollectionTyp

Tags: symfony

I have a **product entity**. And I want to add a
**storage_location** (New York, Berlin)
and **place** (room, shelf, place).

I have created a DB  storage_location and **place with storage_location ID and with product ID**.

In my product form I build the CollectionTyp:

```
->add('inventoryByLocations', CollectionType::class, array(
                'entry_type' => InventoryByLocationType::class,
                'entry_options' => array('label' => false),
                'label' => false,
            ));
```

Here is my problem:
At the moment i have two locations. If I write for an existing product datas in my new databases for each of the two location all works.
But how can I setup 2 "dummy" fields (two locations so fare) if there is no datas in the locations DB?

Comment: You mean placeholder? It's normal to have an empty SELECT if no data.

Comment: why not using a RepositoryFunction to return whatever you like?

Comment: Assuming your `InventoryByLocationType` is bound to a `Location` class: to create a form that shows two empty location fields for you to fill out, you need to add two empty `Location` objects to your `Product` object (e.g. `$product->addLocation(new Location())` ), and then pass the `Product` object into the form (e.g. `$this->createForm(ProductType::class, $product)` ).

Comment: @Marleen Yes this is what im mean.